# Allow editing of a Logic App linked to an Integration Account

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I need to give users access to edit specific Azure Logic App workflows. I find I can support this with the Logic App Contributor role. At times, I have workflows that contain an XML Validation action. I do want users to be able to edit business rules before and after that action, and even configure the action such as selecting a different XSD. However, I do not want them to be able to configure the Integration account that supports the XML Validation action, or even have a read-only view to the Integration account. When I have such an action, a would-be editor is blocked with the error:

*it does not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/join/action' on the linked scope(s)*

Is there a way to apply roles so that a user can edit such a workflow with no direct access to the Integration Account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @SzymonWylezol, MS made a change on its end and the error no longer occurs. In the case where the IA in a separate Resource Group than the Workflow, I find the user must be given the join action permission on the IA, in that Resource Group.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to configure a custom role that matches your scenario.

Essentially you would grant the user the following permissions

```
Microsoft.Logic/workflows/*
Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/join/action
```

The `Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/join/action` perimssion allows the user to modify a logic app linked with an integration account, but does not grant any permissions on the integration account itself (the user would need `Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/*` for that)

You can restrict the `Microsoft.Logic/workflows/*` permission further (e.g. by scoping it down to `write` action only).

Comment: Thank you. This looks good and I hope to find the time to try it out this week. (I have never set up a custom role in Azure, so I need to figure out how to do that.) Also, I made a wishlist suggestion to make this not required as it feels like muda that a join action is even occuring: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/33608854-make-microsoft-logic-integrationaccounts-join-acti

Comment: I am using the following PowerShell script to try and set up a custom role:

Comment: `# Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
Login-AzureRmAccount

$role = Get-AzureRmRoleDefinition "Logic App Contributor"
$role.Id = $null
$role.Name = "External Logic App Contributor"
$role.Description = "Can maintain Logic App Workflows without Integration Account access."
$role.Actions.Clear()
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.Logic/workflows/*")
$role.Actions.Add("Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/join/action")
$role.AssignableScopes.Clear()
$role.AssignableScopes.Add("/subscriptions/[My sub]")
New-AzureRmRoleDefinition -Role $role`

Comment: However, I get the error:

`New-AzureRmRoleDefinition : 'Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/join/action' does not match any of the actions supported 
by the providers.`

Is there some module or something to load in order to refer to the permission?

Comment: @TomSchulte this is actually an issue that needs to be addressed on product side (in order to configure an RBAC role the given action needs to be advertised by the resource provider under their /operations API; the /join action on integration accounts appears to be missing). This should be addressed within a week or so.